# SQL Server 2008 R2, cant create a new DB

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008r2-express

Having real problems creating a DB on my version of SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

I've followed the links to the below but no info provided.

Thanks in advance for any help.

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Create failed for Database 'test'.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.1600.1+((KJ_RTM).100402-1539+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Create+Database&LinkId=20476
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing
>   a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> ---
>
> Directory lookup for the file
>   "D:\DATA\test.mdf" failed with the
>   operating system error 2 (failed to
>   retrieve text for this error. Reason:
>   15100). CREATE DATABASE failed. Some
>   file names listed could not be
>   created. Check related errors.
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5133)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.1600&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=5133&LinkId=20476

Comment: Does the SQL Server user have permission to access D:\DATA\?

Comment: Does your SQL Server machine even *have* a directory called `D:\DATA` ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would assume the issue has to do with the creation of the mdf file in your D:\Data folder.  Can you verify that you have the permissions you need to that location and that you have enough free space?  Also, be sure there isn't already an mdf file by that name at that location.

Comment: Thanks BiggsTRC, I changed the location back to the standard MS one: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA

And it created fine, the problem I have is that I have a load of space on my D: drive and I not enough space on my C: drive to restore it to, I do apply permissions to the D: Drive?

Comment: Got it working, sorry, I hadn't created the D:\DATA folder correctly.

Sorry for wasting time.

Comment: Start simple and work your way up to adjusting permissions.  First verify that there is a folder on your D drive called "Data" (as per marc_s above).  Then verify that you can create a new file in that location (from explorer, not from SQL yet).  If that all works, go into the permissions and TEMPORARILY add rights for everyone to write to the folder.  Try creating the database in SQL.  If it works, the permissions really are an issue.  Verify the account that SQL is running under and give that account access to the Data folder.  Don't forget to remove the extra permissions.

Answer (score 0):

open the DB properties and on the files page (on the right panel) make sure that you dont have database files with duplicate names. if there are change their names